# Can cURL/PHP remotely request a presigned URL for an Amazon S3 Object?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I'm working on a WordPress site that offers free (but temporary) access to a file hosted on Amazon S3. That would be the single use we'd have for the Amazon SDK so it seems pretty absurd to include their whole library and its dependencies on our server for the sake of [that function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createPresignedUrl).

Is there a way to use cURL (PHP) to pass instructions from our server and fetch a presigned URL from Amazon some other way?

Comment: Disk space is cheap

Comment: The point isn't disk space. It's becoming the custodian of thousands of lines of code which I then have to keep up to date.

Comment: You need to use Composer, that will keep the code up to date.  You can exempt the AWS code from your version control.  It is almost always better to use an available library than write your own code, especially with services as complex as Amazon.

Comment: So Amazon doesn't have request endpoints for this kind of thing?

Comment: They do and lots of people use them.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for. Links? Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common misconception that you "fetch" pre-signed URLs from the service, but that isn't true.

They're generated locally in your code (or locally in the SDK code).  Your secret key is used to generate an HMAC digest of a canonical representation of the request that the URL represents.  When the service receives the request (e.g., when the URL is clicked) the service canonicalizes the request, generates the hash from your secret (which is not in the URL, but is known to you and to the service), and if the results match, the request is considered authenticated and allowed to continue to the authorization stage (to ensure that the access key ID presented actually has permission to allow the request).  If the results don't match, then the key or secret are wrong, the signing code on your side has made an error, or the signed URL has been modified since it was signed.  Access denied.

There are, then, no service endpoints that return signed URLs, although you could relatively easily create one for your server to call, using Lambda and API gateway.  Lambda for Node, for example, already has the SDK installed, so you could pass the URL in and return the URL back out, over HTTPS.  Simple but a little bit silly.  You'd have to authenticate the requests from your app using api keys or secret headers, of course, since you wouldn't be able to use native auth, because that would require the SDK. :)

Generating your own code to create signed URLs is not that difficult.   The process is [fully documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) though you'll note on that page that they suggest you use the SDKs.  The reason for this, I suspect, is that even if you are not sufficiently skilled at coding to write your own implementation of the algorithm, it won't be a barrier to entry.

I have written my own implementatiions of this... in fact, I've even written an implementation of the older [V2 signing algorithm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) (which still works in any region that has been online since before 2014) entirely in SQL, as a MySQL stored function (e.g. `SELECT get_signed_url('/bucket/key');` returns a signed url to `GET` an object.  The credentials are stored as variables inside the function)... and given that SQL is probably the least likely language you'd think of for such an operation, this works perfectly.

So you can write it yourself.

But the objection to including the SDK for maintenance reasons is misplaced, I think.

AWS doesn't make breaking changes to their service APIs.

They just don't.  When S3 introduced version 2 of the ListObjects action, V1 still remained available.  Using V2 is recommended, but V1 is *not* deprecated, nor subject to removal.

When Signature Version 4 (mentioned above) was introduced, they added it to all the old regions, left Signature Version 2 in place where it was already available, and deployed new regions only with V4.  Sig V2 is also not deprecated, but V4 is recommended.  Object versioning in S3 was written in such a way that it is 100% backwards compatible with code that doesn't understand object versioning.  The list goes on.

Short of a bug that impacts you (unlikely), or something related to security (also unlikely) the current version of any SDK should not need to be replaced in your project unless you wanted to take advantage of new features, new services, or new AWS regions, which probably doesn't happen all that often in a stable project.